# XSLT Remove tag child elements, but keep content

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml with the following structure:

```
<tuple>
    <something>One</something>
    <somethingelse>Two</somethingelse>
    <somethingextra>
        <tuple>
            <somethingextra2>Three</somethingextra2>
        </tuple>
    </somethingextra>
</tuple>
```

I am trying to figure out how to remove the child `<tuple>` elements, whilst keeping the content.

```
<tuple>
    <something>One</something>
    <somethingelse>Two</somethingelse>
    <somethingextra>
        <somethingextra2>Three</somethingextra2>
    </somethingextra>
</tuple>
```

Any help or suggestion would be very welcome.

Comment: Use the identity template with an override for `tuple`, where instead of copying the element and applying templates to its children, you'll just apply templates to its children.   First, however, you'll need to decide which `tuple` elements to do this for -- perhaps all non-root `tuple` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

michael.hor257k answered the question brilliantly. 
Here is my variation which also handled a few other variations I had.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Convert any atom, table or tuple element to a new element with the name attribute as the element name -->
    <xsl:template match="atom[@name] | table[@name] | tuple[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to distinguish between the root `tuple` element and the `tuple` elements you want to remove.

For example, this will remove *any* `tuple` element that has a parent element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/tuple">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch to an extra mode while traversing your XML Tree. In standard mode you copy all elements, but in mode 'noTuple' you skip the node copy and go back to normal mode.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="somethingextra">
     <xsl:copy>
       <!-- here you switch the mode -->
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="noTuple"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- in standard mode - copy the node an go on in standard mode -->
   <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- matches only for tuple nodes in extra mode -->
   <xsl:template match="tuple" mode="noTuple">
         <!-- back to normal mode -->
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- in extra mode - copy the node an go on in extra mode -->
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="noTuple">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" mode="noTuple"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()" mode="noTuple">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1.** This is not a valid XSLT stylesheet. -- **2.** Even if you fix that, it does not produce the expected result.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thnx, I will check this

Comment: @michael.hor257k edited my post, got now the desired result - sorry, was to hot here :-]